# Is it a natural way to say, "we accept credit card payment" when payment is used in this way

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, word-difference, alternatives

I saw a notice in a local restaurant,

> "we accept credit card payment".

I am wondering if it would be better if the restaurant wrote,

> **we accept payment by credit card.**

Comment: I think it would be better without *payment*, i.e., *We accept credit cards*.

Comment: Either is correct. + what Damkerng said. However, if you want to include *payment*, then it would be more appropriate to say *we accept credit card payments.*

Comment: In the US, the usual line is: **We accept most major credit cards** or **Most major credit cards accepted**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two sentences that you present are entirely synonymous. In this case, there is no difference in their meaning, both connotatively as well as denotatively.

As Damkerng said in the comments, the best option in my opinion (and the most common in my experience) is

> We accept credit cards.

The fact that the credit cards are used for payment doesn't need to be stated - it is implied, because that is the only thing you can use credit cards for.